# Does exiting NodeJS main process causes all child processes to exist as well

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I'm creating a cluster in nodejs application & at some point I'll need to close all the child process(the cluster workers). I was wondering if calling `process.exit(0)` on the master process would be enough to close them all. I tried it & it's seems to work but I want to make sure that this wouldn't cause a memory leak of some kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `child_process` will continue even if node does not, see below:

NODE:

```js
child_process.exec("sleep 20")
process.exit(0)
```

BASH:

```
ps aux | grep "sleep 20"
```

OUTPUT:

```
USERNAME       PID   CPU  MEM  VSZ    RSS TT  S     STARTED   TIME sleep 20
```

The `sleep 20` is still shown as running.